# Wrap a long string to an array of short-enough strings

Tags: python, python-2.x, pygame

I have made a function that wraps text in pygame (i.e. it turns a long string into an array of smaller strings that are short enough so they fit within the given width when rendered in the given font).

My function is below. `text` is the string we want to break up, `font` is a pygame font object, and `max_width` is the number of pixels wide we want the lines to be at maximum (an integer).

```
def wrap_text(text, font, max_width):
    lines = []
    words = text.split(" ")

    while words:
        line = words.pop(0)
        if words:
            width = font.size(" ".join((line, words[0])))[0]
            while width < max_width:
                if words[0] == "\n":
                    # Forced newline when "\n" is in the text
                    del words[0]
                    break
                line = " ".join((line, words.pop(0)))
                if not words:
                    break
                width = font.size(" ".join((line, words[0])))[0]

        if font.size(line)[0] > max_width:
            # When there is only one word on the line and it is still
            # too long to fit within the given maximum width.
            raise ValueError("".join(("\"", line, "\"", " is too long to be wrapped.")))
        lines.append(line)

    return lines
```

**note**: `font.size(string)` returns a tuple containing the width and height the string will be when rendered in the given font.

As you can see, I have the statements `while words:`, `if words:` and `if not words:` all within each other. I have been trying to refactor this by moving things around but I simply cannot think of a way to remove any of the 3 statements above. Any help is much appreciated :). Any comments about anything else in my code is welcome too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Bug

You have a small bug. For `text="abc \\n def"` and `max_width=10` the output is incorrectly `['abc', 'def']` instead of `['abc def']`.

You can greatly simplify the handling of embedded whitespace characters by using `re.split` with a pattern `r'\s+'`.

#### Don't repeat yourself

This (or almost the same) piece of code appears in multiple places: `" ".join((line, words[0]))`.
Look out for duplication like this and use helper functions to eliminate.

#### Overcomplicated string joins

Instead of `" ".join((line, words[0]))`,
it would be a lot simpler to write `line + " " + words[0]`.

#### Simplify the logic

Consider this alternative algorithm:

- Create a word generator: from some text as input, extract the words one by one
- For each word:

  - If the word is too long, raise an error
  - If the current line + word would be too long, then

    - Append the current line to the list of lines
    - Start a new line with the current word
  - If the current line + word is not too long, then append the word to the line
- Append the current line to the list of lines

Implementation:

```
def wrap_text(text, font, max_width):
    def gen_words(text):
        yield from re.split(r'\s+', text)
        # or in older versions of Python:
        # for word in re.split(r'\s+', text):
        #     yield word

    def raise_word_too_long_error(word):
        raise ValueError("\"{}\" is too long to be wrapped.".format(word))

    def too_long(line):
        return font.size(line)[0] > max_width

    words = gen_words(text)
    line = next(words)
    if too_long(line):
        raise_word_too_long_error(line)

    lines = []
    for word in words:
        if too_long(word):
            raise_word_too_long_error(word)

        if too_long(line + " " + word):
            lines.append(line)
            line = word
        else:
            line += " " + word

    lines.append(line)

    return lines
```

Some doctests to verify it works:

```
def _wrap_text_tester(text, max_width):
    """
    >>> _wrap_text_tester("hello there", 7)
    ['hello', 'there']

    >>> _wrap_text_tester("I am legend", 7)
    ['I am', 'legend']

    >>> _wrap_text_tester("abc \\n def", 10)
    ['abc def']

    >>> _wrap_text_tester("toobigtofit", 7)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: "toobigtofit" is too long to be wrapped.

    >>> _wrap_text_tester("in the middle toobigtofit", 7)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: "toobigtofit" is too long to be wrapped.

    >>> _wrap_text_tester("", 7)
    ['']

    """
    return wrap_text(text, font, max_width)
```